# Facebook Graph API - Getting Post Admin Creator

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to obtain the admin_creator field when building out Facebook page posts on my app.  I can get the 'from' field back fine but this only returns the data of the page that created the post.  I need to get the admins name who is logged in when the post was created as is displayed on the Facebook page itself. I thought this would come from the /post_id admin_creator field but I am receiving no data from this call.

```
FB.api("/" + postID + "?fields=application,admin_creator,from,icon,picture,link,is_published,scheduled_publish_time,shares", function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {

    }
});
```

As well in the Graph api explorer when I try to use the admin_creator field nothing is returned and over on the side where the fields are displayed admin_creator is grayed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought this would come from the /post_id admin_creator field but I am receiving no data from this call.

You need to use a page access token to make the request, otherwise the field will not be populated. (This is for privacy reasons, because it is none of a normal user’s business who specifically made a post on a page.)

To get a page access token for any of your pages, you first need `manage_pages` permission, and then you make a request to either `me/accounts` or `/page-id?fields=access_token`. And then you need to pass it as value for a parameter named `access_token` in your FB.api call.

Comment: Thank you, added access_token field to my call and admin_creator was returned.